# How to translate this pyqt4 class with signals into a pyqt5 one?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

I try to translate from pyqt4 to pyqt5 an ObserverWidget class with signal and slot and get an error at the signal to slot connection.

For information: this ObserverWidget is an abstract class for a QObject that will update its state, including its GUI, when receiving notifications.

I have tried to translate the code with the new signal-slot architecture of pyqt5 but I get an error. See below the pyqt4 and pyqt5 codes.

Pyqt4 code that works:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from pyview.lib.patterns import Observer

class ObserverWidget(Observer):

  def __init__(self):
    Observer.__init__(self)
    self._connected = False

  #Non-GUI update.
  def updatedThread(self,subject = None,property = None,value = None):
    pass # overwrite me

  #GUI update.
  def updatedGui(self,subject = None,property = None,value = None):
    pass # overwrite me

  #function called by the notifyer
  def updated(self,subject = None,property = None,value = None):
    self.updatedThread(subject,property,value)
    if not self._connected:
      self.connect(self,SIGNAL("processUpdate(PyQt_PyObject)"),self.processUpdate,Qt.QueuedConnection | Qt.UniqueConnection)  
      self._connected = True
    self.emit(SIGNAL("processUpdate(PyQt_PyObject)"),[subject,property,value])

  def processUpdate(self,args):
    self.updatedGui(*args)
```

This works well

```
ow=ObserverWidget()
ow.updated(subject,property,value)
```

Wrong pyqt5 code that do not work:

```
class ObserverWidget(QObject, Observer):

    processUpdateSignal = pyqtSignal('PyQt_PyObject')

    @ pyqtSlot('PyQt_PyObject')
    def processUpdate(self, argsList):
        self.updatedGui(*argsList)

    def __init__(self):
        Observer.__init__(self)
        self._connected = False

    def updatedThread(self, subject=None, property=None, value=None):
        pass # please overwrite me

    def updatedGui(self, subject=None, property=None, value=None):
        pass # please overwrite me

    def updated(self, subject=None, property=None, value=None):
        self.updatedThread(subject, property, value)
        if not self._connected:
            self.processUpdateSignal.connect(self.processUpdate, Qt.QueuedConnection | Qt.UniqueConnection)
            self._connected = True
        self.processUpdateSignal.emit([subject, property, value])
```

Running the same code

```
ow=ObserverWidget()
ow.updated(subject,property,value)
```

yields the following error:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal ow::processUpdateSignal(PyQt_PyObject)
TypeError: connect() failed between ObserverWidget.processUpdateSignal[PyQt_PyObject] and processUpdate()
```

(Note that adding `QObject.__init__(self)` in the creator does not help). 
Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: change to: `processUpdateSignal = pyqtSignal(object)` and `@pyqtSlot(object)`

Comment: Thank you but it does not work and give the very same error.

Comment: change `Observer.__init__(self)` to `super().__init__()`

Comment: I have changed for `super(ObserverWidget, self).__init__()` but now the widgets in ow do not react any more... But where do you consider that this question is answered?

Comment: From what you indicate to me, I suspect that you no longer have the initial error message (which probably has already been solved) but that you have another error different from what you indicated in your post, so if so, I recommend you publish a new post where you provide a [mre]

Comment: I have marked as duplicate the error that you indicate, if you have another problem then create a new post as I indicated

Comment: The solution was to change for `class ObserverWidget(object, Observer)`, for
`processUpdateSignal = pyqtSignal(list)` and for `@pyqtSlot(list)`. The use of `object` instead of `QObject` in the class definition solved the problem, which I don't understand at all. From that point of view, it is not a duplicate, and any explanation is welcome.

Comment: It seems to me that Observer is already a QObject but I do not see any explanation, on the other hand it seems that it has not reviewed the duplicate question and has only changed you with my comment, pyqtSignal should receive the type of data that it will send, in your case you don't point it out so the generic case is object but that does not imply that list is not valid.

Comment: No, Observer is my own class and has nothing to do with Qt. And yes replacing list by object or 'PyQt_PyObject' in pyqtSignal() and @pyqtSlot() also works. But ObserverWidget(QObject, Observer) or ObserverWidget(Observer) do not. I could get my code working only with ObserverWidget(object, Observer)!?